# Check live if UITextField is not empty

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, uialertview, xcode8

I have a UIAlertView which includes an UITextField. The alert view has tow buttons. One normal "dismiss" button and another "add". The "add" button should just be clickable if the UITextField is not empty. I don't know how to check in "real time" if the field is empty. I only saw the possibility to check the textField if the button has been clicked. But that's not what  want ("add" button should be grayed out if thextField is empty). Do you have a solution for this? Thanks for your effort!

I'm using Swift 3 and Xcode 8

Comment: You'll want to use the UITextFieldDelegate to listen for changes.

Comment: `UIAlertView` was deprecated a while ago. You should be using `UIAlertController`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to create you UIAlertAction as a global variable like this

```
var alertAction = UIAlertAction()
```

Now while adding that action to UIAlertController you need to set the property `isEnabled` as false like in the below code

```
alertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Click", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil)
alertAction.isEnabled = false
let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: "Message", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
alert.addTextField { (textField) in
    textField.delegate = self
}        
alert.addAction(alertAction)
self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

After this in the delegate method shouldChangeCharacter you need to get if the value is entered in the UITextField then you need to enable that button like this

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
        let userEnteredString = textField.text
        let newString = (userEnteredString! as NSString).replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string) as NSString
        if  newString != ""{
            alertAction.isEnabled = true
        } else {
            alertAction.isEnabled = false
        }
        return true
    }
```

Here is a working example

[image]

Comment: Do you know what to do to make this a utility class so that you don't have to implement the delegate pattern in every viewcontroller where you want to use this? I have some issues with it (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40837477/uialertcontroller-utility-class-fails-to-call-uitextfield-delegate-or-target-but/40838396#40838396)

Answer (score 0):

You can TextFieldDelegate. Set your current view Controller or view as a delegate.like

```
let textTextField = UITextField()
textTextField.delegate = self
```

when textfield change the below method will be called.

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, 
shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, 
      replacementString string: String) -> Bool
```

or you can use the notification  **UITextFieldTextDidChange** .it will posted when text of textfield will change.

The affected text field is stored in the object parameter of the notification.

Answer (score -1):

Check text field text:

```
if textField.text != nil && textField.text != "" {
    print("you can enable your add button")
}else{
    print("empty text field")
}
```

Comment: questing is not asking something like this , yeah this is ok to check wether the textField is empty or not.